# Error when I refresh count down it's restart

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdown

I have this code for CountDown and When I refresh the page It's count from the beginning.
I want to continue counting from where it arrived even after several times of the update:
I have this code for CountDown and When I refresh the page It's count from the beginning.
I want to continue counting from where it arrived even after several times of the update:

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }
  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  /*font-family: sans-serif;*/
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  color: #e5534c;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
}

#clockdiv {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #e5534c;
  display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div>span {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #515251;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
}

.smalltext {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The remaining duration of the white Friday cuts</h1>
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Day</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hour</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minute</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Save the countdown in `sessionStorage`, and start from there when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Why don't you set `deadline` to the actual time instead of always adding 15 days to the current time?

Comment: Thanks Barmar if you give more details how save it in sessionStorage

Comment: and if you can rewrite the code with deadline

Comment: this code from CodePen https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq

Answer (score 1):

Save `deadline` in [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Replace the two lines:

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

with this:

```
var deadline;
var savedDeadline = sessionStorage.getItem("deadline");
if (savedDeadline) {
    deadline = parseInt(savedDeadline);
} else {
    deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    sessionStorage.setItem("deadline", deadline);
}
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I do not know anything about sessionStorage if you can rewrite the code fully and I thank you again

Comment: I'm not going to rewrite the whole thing when I'm just replacing two lines. I've updated the answer to explain exactly how this fits in.

Comment: I included a link to the `sessionStorage` documentation. If that's not enough, I'm sure you can find tutorials using Google.